# How to update Moneybookers(Skrill) Payment URL

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

We are using phoenix/moneybookers extension which comes as default in Magento 1.9.x community edition.

Recently, we get an email from Skrill to update the payment URL from http://www.moneybookers.com/app/payment.pl to https://pay.skrill.com

When can we get updated version for this? 
Do you have any patch for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use new Skrill official module instead

[get it in marketplace](https://marketplace.magento.com/skrill-skrill-hosted-payment-solution.html)